# with IDEA, do you have to organize by package or you can do by folder if you want?

Tags: java, intellij-idea

with IDEA, do you have to organize by package or you can do by folder if you want?

When using packages, I am forced to put all files under a package, but sometimes I want a folder to hold all 'xxxService' related files like the interface + Impl + helpers.

Answer (score 0):

The project tab can organise files and folders into favourites. Right click on the file and in the context menu is an Add To Favourites option. From there you can either add to a favourites list you've already created, or create a new list.
So with that, you'd be able to create a view for all your relevant xxxService files.